# Confusion regarding actuator

Tags: control, control-system, terminology

Almost all of the block diagram shown in control systems texts show a controller block and a system/plant block, but they don't show an actuator block.

So I am confused, should we consider thr actuator as part of the controller or the plant?

Comment: What does the actuator do? What does the plant output?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the control system. Many academic control systems don't include a sensor. Most real world control systems do.

I would consider this to be a more comprehensive diagram with the sensor included:

[image]
Source: https://ledin.com/control-systems-basics/

> So I am confused, should we consider thr actuator as part of the
> controller or the plant?

It really depends on the system being modeled. For example a temperature control system, the plant might be a block of aluminum, the actuator a PWM voltage control connected to a heater and the control algorithm a digital PID running on a processor, the sensor might be a DAC connected to a thermistor.

One could model the heater with the block or with the actuator, just depends on where you draw the line, at the end of the day one just needs to keep track of how things are being modeled and what definitions are used.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does not really matter. I consider it as part of the plant. More specifically as an interface between the controller and the plant. It is definitely not part of the control algorithm.